# Is there a Visual Studio extension that adds Find window like in WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio, webstorm, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

There is a nice find window in WebStorm. Is there a way to add such window to Visual Studio? Current Find Results window in VS looks really outdated.

[image: WebStorm Find window]

Comment: What features eaxctly are you looking for? Colored output? See https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496

Comment: Search window that works the same fast and looks good as the one in WebStorm. Search term is highlighted, there is short file name in the end, easy up/down keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entrian Source Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntrianSolutions-RichieHindle.EntrianSourceSearchAfulltextindexsearchengineforyo) extension provides syntax high­lighted search results and multiple advanced search options:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! It has some issues with Russian language but it still very good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For symbol search you can use Find All References (Shift+F12):

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know about it. Looks good but it doesn't work for HTML/CSS/JS.