# Is There a Find Tool for Visual Studio Like The One In Android Studio

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment

I am aware of the basic Find tool provided in VS, but I don't think it's as good as the one in Anrdroid Studio.  Specifically, I like that the one in Android Studio shows *the number of matches it finds*.
I don't see this feature in Visual Studio's version of Find - I'm using 2017 and ReSharper.  Productivity Power Tools for 2017 doesn't seem to improve the basic Find tool either.

Comment: Are you looking at “Find in Files” / ctrl-shift-f?  Coulda sworn that counted matches.

Comment: Ah, not `matches`....`matched lines`.  Yeah...kinda odd they don't include `matches`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838632/is-there-a-visual-studio-extension-that-adds-find-window-like-in-webstorm